# is there a way of defining function in models and save them to database as default by also filtering the fields? in Python Djnago

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

what i want to do is compute the value in percent for each learning styles there are and save them as default value to the field `**result** on AssessmentLearningStyle` model

here is the model

```
    #MODEL_FOURTEEN
class QuestionResults(models.Model):
    id                          = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    student                     = models.ForeignKey(to=FacilityUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    question                    = models.ForeignKey(to=QuestionLearningStyle, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    agree                       = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    disagree                    = models.BooleanField(null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.question)

#MODEL_FIFTEEN
class AssessmentLearningStyle(models.Model):
    @property
    def test(self):
        u = self.learning_style
        s = 0
        if u == QuestionResults.question.learning_style:
            k = int(QuestionResults.objects.filter(agree=True, question__learning_style=self.learning_style).count())
            l = int(QuestionResults.objects.filter(question__learning_style=self.learning_style).count())
            if l != 0:
                s = (k/l) * 100
            else:
                s = 0  
        return float(s)
    id                          = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    student                     = models.ForeignKey(to=FacilityUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    assessent_date              = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True) 
    learning_style              = models.ForeignKey(to=LearningStyle, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    result                      = models.FloatField(default=test, editable=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.student)
```

i want to save the value of `test function` to the result field...but it says float can't accept the value of property...and if i remove property... this method doesn't work at all...can you guys help me to fix this or show me a better way of doing this?

> Blockquote

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: i copied the code now...can you check it?

Comment: @StephenGorge you did the correct thing

Comment: @Carlos well .. i don't know why i'm getting an error

Answer (score 1):

Have tried overriding the save function

```
Class AssignmentLearningStyle(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.result = self.test
        super(AssignmentLearningStyle, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: hey @RohanBaddii, i tried that and it shows this error


**"'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'learning_style'**
Request Method: POST
Exception Value: 
**'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'learning_style'"**

Comment: I need to see your QuestionLearningStyle model.